# Perl parse CSV file "fill" and "null" fields

Tags: perl, parsing, null

Okay - I'm going to post my entire script since I get chastised when I don't do it - even though, last time I did that I got chastised for posting the whole script.  I simply need to know if the one line I originally asked about would work.  ENTIRE SCRIPT (which was working just fine until the other dept gave me their data entirely differently than what we were originally told it would be) TO FOLLOW AT THE END

I'm parsing through and scrubbing a CSV file to make it ready to be loaded in a MySQL table. It is loaded through the table via someone else's "batch Java program" and if any field is empty the batch file stops with an error.

I've been told to just put in a blank space whenever there's an empty field in any record. Would something as simple as this work?

```
if ( ! length $fields[2] ) { 
    $_ = ' ' for $fields[2];
}
```

And would there be a way to check either various multiple fields at once?  Or what might be better would be to check ALL the fields (this is after the record has been split) as the last thing I do just before writing the record back out to the CSV file.

Here's the entire script.  Please don't tell me how what I'm doing within the already working script is not how you would do it. -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my $filename = 'mistints_1505_comma.csv';
#my $filename = 'test.csv';

# Open input file
open my $FH, $filename
  or die "Could not read from $filename <$!>, program halting.";

# Open error handling file
open ( my $ERR_FH, '>', "errorFiles1505.csv" ) or die $!;

# Read the header line of the input file and print to screen.
chomp(my $line = <$FH>);
my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
print Dumper(@fields), $/;

my @data;

# Read the lines one by one.
while($line = <$FH>) {

    chomp($line);

# Scrub data of characters that cause scripting problems down the line.
    $line =~ s/[\'\\]/ /g;

# split the fields of each record

    my @fields = split(/,/, $line);

# Check if the storeNbr field is empty.  If so, write record to error file.
    if (!length $fields[28]) {
        chomp (@fields);
        my $str = join ',', @fields;
        print $ERR_FH "$str\n";
        }
    else
    {

# Concatenate the first three fields and add to the beginning of each record
    unshift @fields, join '_', @fields[28..30];

# Format the DATE fields for MySQL
    $_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for @fields[10,14,24,26];

# Scrub colons from the data
    $line =~ s/:/ /g;

# If Spectro_Model is "UNKNOWN", change
    if($fields[22] eq "UNKNOWN"){
        $_ = 'UNKNOW' for $fields[22];
        }

# If tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[10]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[10];
        }

# If init_tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[14]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[14];
        }

# If update_tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[24]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[24];
        }

# If cancel_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[26]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[26];
        }

# Format the PROD_NBR field by deleting any leading zeros before decimals.
    $fields[12] =~ s/^\s*0\././;

# put the records back
    push @data, \@fields;
}
}

close $FH;
close $ERR_FH;

print "Unsorted:\n", Dumper(@data); #, $/;

#Sort the clean files on Primary Key, initTranDate, updateTranDate, and updateTranTime
@data = sort {
    $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] ||
    $a->[14] cmp $b->[14] ||
    $a->[26] cmp $b->[26] ||
    $a->[27] cmp $b-> [27]
} @data;

#open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/parsedMistints.csv';
open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/cleaned1505.csv';
print $OFH join(',', @$_), $/ for @data;
close $OFH;

exit;
```

Comment: So `null` in your context is a comma separated field with no data?   I was wondering what might happen if you changed every comma a comma bracketed by whilespace.  Like `1,$s/,/ , /g` would do in `vi`.  Would that mangle it too much, or is it padding tolerant?  If there was no worry about a `null` at the beginning or at end of a line, you could get by with just a one space pad

Comment: @BigRedEO: You don't say what you want to do this to. Are you processing the raw comma-separated lines of text from the file, or have you split it into an array, or what? And do you want just a literal space, or a space surrounded by quotes?

Comment: @Borodin - I don't want to post the entire script - last time I did that, I got chastised left and right for it.  Now when I don't post it, people mark my question down.  Sometimes, there's no winning with stackoverflow

Comment: @BigRedEO  I'd suggest that you simply consider carefully the comments and feedback that you've been getting from people on your questions, rather than getting frustrated.  Please appreciate that all these _people_ do give you their time and effort, and expertise.  You can help by trying your best to post good and articulate questions (which sometimes isn't easy).

Comment: Thanks @zdim - yet nobody's actually answered my question.

Comment: @zdim - But you're right about the frustrating part - whenever I'm writing in Powershell and go to powershell dot com, those people there are so genuinely helpful.  Here, everyone wants to see all of your code, tell you how they would do it all differently (even though most of what you have is already working for you) and then don't actually answer your question.  I wish I could delete questions and start all over after all the upbraids go through first.

Comment: @BigRedEO  Let me suggest this -- perhaphs your questions on that powershell forum are just better (easy to happen if you're more comfortable with that material) ?  If you don't get straight answers here it can only mean that the questions aren't clear enough (brief and clear anwers are prized here).  I've looked through your questions and through responses you were getting.  Everyone you get answers from would blow away your problem in one line if that were possible. But re-read their comments and solutions when you have a little time, you'll find all answers there.

Comment: I am living proof that there is winning with stackoverflow.

Comment: @BigRedEO: *"last time I did that I got chastised for posting the whole script"* The thing is, we need to see as much information as possible without having to sift through a pile of junk.  Don't forget that you're asking for a *favour* here—we don't get anything but your thanks—and if you can't be bothered to post your data or reduce your code so that it's compact but still misbehaves, then it's hard to be bothered to help you. Powershell questions are likely to be much less about syntax, and the people who suggest a rewrite are trying to help you avoid the same problem again

Comment: @BigRedEO: Note that I've asked you three times now and you still haven't shown any data. Meanwhile your only comment to my answer is *"almost there - this section did not work"*. Only my manager, who authorises my salary, gets to talk like that to me. You are just being rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you have split a record on commas `,`, and you want to alter all fields that are empty strings to contain a single space

I would write this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $record = 'a,b,c,,e,,g,,i,,k,,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t';

my @fields = map { $_ eq "" ? ' ' : $_ } split /,/, $record;


use Data::Dump;
dd \@fields;
```

#### output

```
[ "a", "b", "c", " ", "e", " ", "g", " ", "i", " ", "k", " ", "m" .. "t" ]
```

Alternatively, if you have some fields that need to be set to something different if they are empty, you can set up an array of defaults

That would look like this. All of the `@defaults` array is set to spaces except for fields 10, 11 and 12, which are `0000-00-00`. These are picked up after the record is split

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @defaults = (' ') x 20;

$defaults[$_] = '0000-00-00' for 9, 10, 11;

my $record = 'a,b,c,,e,,g,,i,,k,,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t';

my @fields = split /,/, $record;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#fields ) {
    $fields[$i] = $defaults[$i] if $fields[$i] eq '';
}


use Data::Dump;
dd \@fields;
```

#### output

```
[ "a", "b", "c", " ", "e", " ", "g", " ", "i", "0000-00-00", "k", "0000-00-00", "m" .. "t" ]
```

---

Having seen your full program, I recommend something like this. If you had shown a sample of your input data then I could have used a hash to refer to column names instead of numbers, making it much more readable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my $filename = 'mistints_1505_comma.csv';
#my $filename = 'test.csv';

open my $FH, $filename
        or die "Could not read from $filename <$!>, program halting.";

open( my $ERR_FH, '>', "errorFiles1505.csv" ) or die $!;

chomp( my $line = <$FH> );
my @fields = split /,/, $line;    #/
print Dumper( \@fields ), "\n";

my @data;

# Read the lines one by one.
while ( <$FH> ) {

    chomp;

    # Scrub data of characters that cause scripting problems down the line.
    tr/'\\/  /;                   #'

    my @fields = split /,/;       #/

    # Check if the storeNbr field is empty.  If so, write record to error file.

    if ( $fields[28] eq "" ) {
        my $str = join ',', @fields;
        print $ERR_FH "$str\n";
        next;
    }

    # Concatenate the first three fields and add to the beginning of each record
    unshift @fields, join '_', @fields[ 28 .. 30 ];

    # Format the DATE fields for MySQL
    $_ = join '-', ( split /\// )[ 2, 0, 1 ] for @fields[ 10, 14, 24, 26 ];

    # Scrub colons from the data
    tr/://d;                      #/

    my $i = 0;
    for ( @fields ) {

        # If "Spectro_Model" is "UNKNOWN" then change to "UNKNOW"
        if ( $i == 22 ) {
            $_ = 'UNKNOW' if $_ eq 'UNKNOWN';
        }

        # If a date field is blank then insert 0000-00-00
        elsif ( grep { $i == $_ } 10, 14, 24, 26 ) {
            $_ = '0000-00-00' if $_ eq "";
        }

        # Format the PROD_NBR field by deleting any leading zeros before decimals.
        elsif ( $i == 12 ) {
            s/^\s*0\././;
        }

        # Change all remaining empty fields to a single space
        else {
            $_ = ' ' if $_ eq "";
        }

        ++$i;
    }

    push @data, \@fields;
}

close $FH;
close $ERR_FH;

print "Unsorted:\n", Dumper(@data);    #, $/;

#Sort the clean files on Primary Key, initTranDate, updateTranDate, and updateTranTime
@data = sort {
    $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]   or
    $a->[14] cmp $b->[14] or
    $a->[26] cmp $b->[26] or
    $a->[27] cmp $b->[27]
} @data;

#open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/parsedMistints.csv';
open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/cleaned1505.csv' or die $!;
print $OFH join(',', @$_), $/ for @data;
close $OFH;
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  You and zdim have helped in the past and I think your answer helps me greatly.  Part of my frustration also stems from being told one thing and working with one set of data, only to have a completely different set of data from the other depts, which throws everything off for me.

Comment: almost there - this section did not work -         `# If tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
        elsif ( grep { $i == $_ } 10, 14, 24, 26 ) {
            $_ = '0000-00-00' if $_ eq "";
        }`    It didn't change any of the empty or blank date fields to the 0000-00-00.  I think I originally tried something like this and it would only check field 10 and if that wasn't blank, it would leave the rest alone.  Instead I now have blank spaces there.

Comment: Okay, fixed. I simply incremented the index in the wrong place. But I repeat: it could be a whole lot nicer if the behaviour could be dependent on the column name instead of the field index, but I can't write that without seeing your data

Comment: There is a header record for each file I'm scrubbing - would that make a difference, even though it's being eliminated from the scrubbed file?

Comment: the move of the increment did work!  Thank you.  Now I've got what I've been told is needed - and THEIR program still won't load the files.  That is their issue - I'm seeing that wherever there's an INT, it still considers it "null" even with the blank space, and won't load.  But at least my part is done.  Thank you again!

Comment: @BigRedEO: I hope you've been left with a better attitude to what we are trying to do? We normally ask for a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) so that we can help you properly. But that requires the person raising the question to actually do some work, which rarely goes down well. It's a shame that you see us as being less helpful than the PowerShell guys, but Perl is really a different deal, and a problem may be far away elsewhere in your code or even in your data

Comment: @BigRedEO: If we can see nothing wrong in what you have posted then we can just say "nothing wrong there!" or we can ask to see more of your code or data. Which would you prefer? As it stands, you still haven't offered me any data; so you are left with a program that uses *magic numbers* instead of column names. You could write much better code, and I'm baffled why you would want to stop at something that just barely works

Comment: @BigRedEO: By the way, if you have just copied my solution and submitted it as a job complete, then why don't you owe me a couple days' salary, let's say $300?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you did it before splitting into `$fields`, you ought to be able to do something like

```
# assuming a CSV line is in $_
#pad null at start of line
s/^,/ ,/;

#pad nulls in the middle
s/,,/, ,/g;

#pad null at the end
s/,$/, /;
```

Comment: The issue is that I have several fields that if they are null (!length), then I have to add something to them other than a blank space, such as "0000-00-00" for some date fields and a few other items like that.  Once I've made all those necessary replacements first, then I'd want to check for any other fields that are zero length and put in a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to roll out your own CSV parsing code. Use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) or [Text::CSV::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~babf/Text-CSV-Slurp-1.03/lib/Text/CSV/Slurp.pm).

With Text::CSV you could do something like

```
$line   = $csv->string();             # get the combined string
$status  = $csv->parse($line);        # parse a CSV string into fields
@columns = map {defined $_ ? $_ : " "} $csv->fields(); # get the parsed fields
```

Are you really sure you want to replace nulls with spaces? I'd say if the field is undefined it should be NULL in db.

Comment: `split /,/` is perfectly satisfactory if there are no quoted fields in the data

Comment: @jira - No Text:CSV of any kind available to me, nor will there be.  My script already fine and dandy and working correctly with the original "test" data I was given.  Then the actual data I was given from another dept is what threw in this extra trouble.